# why my high score label updates only once?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to implement the high score label in a demo project I'm working on.
I declare the integer and long integer as follows:

```
SKLabelNode *_scoreLabel;
int _meter;
SKLabelNode *_highScoreLabel;
NSInteger _meter1;
```

then in `- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` i add declare the label and add the nsuser default:

```
[self initScoreLabel];
[self initHighScoreLabel];

_meter1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
if (_meter > _meter1) {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_meter1 forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
}
```

this is how i add the label too:

```
- (void)initHighScoreLabel {
  _meter1 = 0;
  _highScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thonburi-Bold"];
  _highScoreLabel.text = @"0 High Score";
  _highScoreLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
  // _scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;// | SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline;
  _highScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(450, self.frame.size.height - _highScoreLabel.frame.size.height * 1.5);
  [self addChild:_highScoreLabel];
}
```

then in `game over` I add the high score:

```
_meter1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];

if (_meter > _meter1) {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_meter forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
}
```

and at last in `- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime` I add the update as follows:

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
  if (_isGameOver) {
    return;
  }

  if (_lastUpdateTime) {
    _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
  } else {
    _dt = 0;
  }
  _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

  // Runner faster than normal
  if (_runnerState == incredible) {
    _meter += INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC / BG_POINTS_PER_SEC;
    _meter1 += INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC / BG_POINTS_PER_SEC;
  } else {
    ++_meter;
    ++_meter1;
  }
  _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Meters", _meter];
  _highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li High Score",(long) _meter1];

  [self checkCollisions];
}
```

The label shows up in the right location and adds the score plus high score.
But only once after the player dies.

The first time the player dies, the high score updates, but if the player dies for the second time, the high score only shows the first update.

Can some one help me out to understand what i am doing wrong?

Edit:

I did add some slog and everything is firing the right way. score updates and high score adds up to but still only once. here is the whole game scene class. can anyone see where i did go wrong?

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "SKTAudio.h"
#import "Levels.h"
#import "StartScene.h"
#import "EndScene.h"

// the position X of the runner on the screen
static const float RUNNER_X = 120.0;
static const float RUNNER_HEIGHT = 56.0;
static const float JUMP_HEIGHT = 100.0;

// background scrolling speed
static const float BG_POINTS_PER_SEC = 200.0;
static const float INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC = 600.0;

static const int COINS_PER_MAP = 10;
static const int ROCKS_PER_MAP = 2;
static const float BG_WIDTH = 1440;

static const int COIN_RANDOM_FACTOR = (int) (BG_WIDTH / COINS_PER_MAP * 2);
static const int ROCK_RANDOM_FACTOR = (int) (BG_WIDTH / ROCKS_PER_MAP * 2);


#define BG_NAME @"bg"
#define GROUND_NAME @"ground"
#define COIN_NAME @"coin"
#define ROCK_NAME @"rock"
#define RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY @"runnerAnimation"
#define RUNNER_EMITTER @"runnerEmitter"

enum RunnerState {
    running,
    jumping,
    crouching,
    incredible
};

static inline CGPoint CGPointAdd(const CGPoint a,
                                 const CGPoint b) {
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(const CGPoint a,
                                            const CGFloat b) {
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}

@interface MyScene() {
    SKSpriteNode *_runner;
    SKAction *_runningAnimation;
    SKAction *_jumpAnimation;
    SKAction *_crouchAnimation;
    SKAction *_coinAnimation;
    SKEmitterNode *_runnerEmitter;

    SKLabelNode *_scoreLabel;
    int _meter;
    SKLabelNode *_highScoreLabel;
    NSInteger _meter1;
    SKLabelNode *_coinsLabel;
    int _coins;

    NSTimeInterval _lastUpdateTime;
    // time diff
    NSTimeInterval _dt;

    CGFloat _groundHalfHeight;

    enum RunnerState _runnerState;
    SKNode *_bgLayer;

    BOOL _isGameOver;
}
@end

@implementation MyScene

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        _bgLayer = [SKNode node];
        [self addChild:_bgLayer];
        [self initMap];

        [self initScoreLabel];
        [self initHighScoreLabel];
        [self initCoinsLabel];

        // adding background sound effect
        [[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"background.mp3"];

        [self initRunnerAnimation];
        [_runner runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_runningAnimation] withKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
        _runnerState = running;

        [self initRunnerParticle];

        [self initJumpAnimation];
        [self initCrouchAnimation];
        [self initCoinAnimation];
        _meter1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];

        if (_meter > _meter1) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_meter1 forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
        }

        // coins for fist map
        // [self generateRandomCoins:_ground.size.width/4];

        // coins for second map
        // int x = _ground.position.x;
        // [self generateRandomCoins:x];

        // rocks for second map
        // [self generateRandomRocks:x];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initRunnerParticle {
    _runnerEmitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RunnerParticle" ofType:@"sks"]];
    _runnerEmitter.position = CGPointMake(_runner.size.width / 2.0, _runner.size.height / 2.0);
    _runnerEmitter.name = RUNNER_EMITTER;
}

- (void)initCoinsLabel {
    _coins = 0;
    _coinsLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thonburi-Bold"];
    _coinsLabel.text = @"Coins: 0";
    _coinsLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    // _coinsLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;// | SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline;
    _coinsLabel.position = CGPointMake(50, self.frame.size.height - _coinsLabel.frame.size.height * 1.5);
    [self addChild:_coinsLabel];
}

- (void)initScoreLabel {
    _meter = 0;
    _scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thonburi-Bold"];
    _scoreLabel.text = @"0 Meter";
    _scoreLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    // _scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;// | SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline;
    _scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(250, self.frame.size.height - _scoreLabel.frame.size.height * 1.5);
    [self addChild:_scoreLabel];

}
- (void)initHighScoreLabel {
    _meter1 = 0;
    _highScoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Thonburi-Bold"];
    _highScoreLabel.text = @"0 High Score";
    _highScoreLabel.fontSize = 20.0;
    // _scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeRight;// | SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBaseline;
    _highScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(450, self.frame.size.height - _highScoreLabel.frame.size.height * 1.5);
    [self addChild:_highScoreLabel];

}

- (void)initMap {
    // adding the background
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        SKSpriteNode *map = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Map0%d", i]];
        map.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        map.position = CGPointMake(i * map.size.width, 0);;
        map.name = BG_NAME;
        [_bgLayer addChild:map];
    }

    // adding the ground
    SKSpriteNode *ground;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ground0%d", i]];
        ground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        ground.position = CGPointMake(i * ground.size.width, 0);;
        ground.name = GROUND_NAME;
        _groundHalfHeight = ground.size.height / 2.0;
        [_bgLayer addChild:ground];
    }
}

- (void)initRunnerAnimation {
    // adding the runner
    _runner = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"runner0"];
    _runner.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    _runner.position = CGPointMake(RUNNER_X, self.frame.origin.y + _groundHalfHeight + RUNNER_HEIGHT / 2.0);
    [self addChild:_runner];

    // adding running animation
    NSMutableArray *textures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"runner%d", i];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [textures addObject:texture];
    }

    _runningAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.1];
}

- (void)initCrouchAnimation {
    // adding crouch animation
    _crouchAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:@[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"runnerCrouch0"]] timePerFrame:1.4 resize:YES restore:YES];
}

- (void)initJumpAnimation {
    // adding jump animation
    NSMutableArray *jumpUpTextures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"runnerJumpUp%d", i];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [jumpUpTextures addObject:texture];
    }

    SKAction *jumpUpAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:jumpUpTextures timePerFrame:0.2 resize:YES restore:YES];
    SKAction *moveUpAction = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:JUMP_HEIGHT duration:0.8];
    SKAction *jumpUpAction = [SKAction group:@[jumpUpAnimation, moveUpAction]];

    NSMutableArray *jumpDownTextures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"runnerJumpDown%d", i];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [jumpDownTextures addObject:texture];
    }

    SKAction *jumpDownAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:jumpDownTextures timePerFrame:0.3 resize:YES restore:YES];
    SKAction *moveDownAction = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-JUMP_HEIGHT duration:0.6];
    SKAction *jumpDownAction = [SKAction group:@[jumpDownAnimation, moveDownAction]];

    _jumpAnimation = [SKAction sequence:@[jumpUpAction, jumpDownAction]];
}

- (void)initCoinAnimation {
    // adding coin animation
    NSMutableArray *coinTextures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"coin%d", i];
        SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [coinTextures addObject:texture];
    }
    _coinAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:coinTextures timePerFrame:0.1];
}

- (void)moveBackground {
    CGPoint bgVelocity;
    if (_runnerState == incredible) {
        bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC, 0);
    }
    else {
        bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-BG_POINTS_PER_SEC, 0);
    }
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMultiplyScalar(bgVelocity, _dt);

    // move the map
    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:BG_NAME usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        bg.position = CGPointAdd(bg.position, amtToMove);
        if (bg.position.x <= -bg.size.width) {
            int x = (int) (bg.position.x + bg.size.width * 2);
            bg.position = CGPointMake(x, bg.position.y);

            // NSLog(@"%f %f", bg.position.x, bg.size.width);
            // coins for new map
            [self generateRandomCoins:x];
            [self generateRandomRocks:x];
        }
    }];

    // move the ground
    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:GROUND_NAME usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *ground = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        ground.position = CGPointAdd(ground.position, amtToMove);
        if (ground.position.x <= -ground.size.width) {
            int x = (int) (ground.position.x + ground.size.width * 2);
            ground.position = CGPointMake(x, ground.position.y);
        }
    }];

    [self moveObject:COIN_NAME to:amtToMove];
    [self moveObject:ROCK_NAME to:amtToMove];
}

- (void)moveObject:(NSString *)name to:(CGPoint)amtToMove {
    // move coins
    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:name usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKSpriteNode *coin = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
        coin.position = CGPointAdd(coin.position, amtToMove);
        if (coin.position.x <= -coin.size.width) {
            // off the screen, remove itself
            [coin removeFromParent];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeUp:)];
    swipeUpGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpGestureRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeDown:)];
    swipeDownGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownGestureRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
    swipeRightGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Right!");
    [self startIncredibleMode];
}

- (void)startIncredibleMode {
    if (_runnerState != running) {
        return;
    }
    _runnerState = incredible;
    // stop it after 5 sec
    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5.0];
    [_runner runAction:wait completion:^{
        _runnerState = running;
        [_runner removeChildrenInArray:@[_runnerEmitter]];
    }];
    [_runner addChild:_runnerEmitter];
}

- (void)handleSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Up!");
    [self jump];
}

- (void)jump {
    if (_runnerState != running) {
        return;
    }
    _runnerState = jumping;
    [_runner removeActionForKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
    [_runner runAction:_jumpAnimation completion:^{
        [_runner removeAllActions];
        [_runner runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_runningAnimation] withKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
        _runnerState = running;
    }];
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"jump.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
}

- (void)handleSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe Down!");
    [self crouch];
}

- (void)crouch {
    if (_runnerState != running) {
        return;
    }
    _runnerState = crouching;
    [_runner removeActionForKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
    [_runner runAction:_crouchAnimation completion:^{
        [_runner removeAllActions];
        [_runner runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_runningAnimation] withKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
        _runnerState = running;
    }];
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"crouch.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
}


- (void)generateRandomCoins:(int)x {
    for (int i = 0; i < COINS_PER_MAP; ++i) {
        x += (arc4random() % COIN_RANDOM_FACTOR);
        SKSpriteNode *coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"coin0"];
        coin.position = CGPointMake(x, _groundHalfHeight + RUNNER_HEIGHT / 2.0);
        coin.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        coin.name = COIN_NAME;
        [coin runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_coinAnimation]];
        [_bgLayer addChild:coin];
    }
}

- (void)generateRandomRocks:(int)x {
    SKSpriteNode *rock = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rock"];
    int x1 = x + (arc4random() % ROCK_RANDOM_FACTOR);
    rock.position = CGPointMake(x1, _groundHalfHeight + RUNNER_HEIGHT / 2.0);
    rock.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    rock.name = ROCK_NAME;
    [_bgLayer addChild:rock];

    int x2 = x + (arc4random() % ROCK_RANDOM_FACTOR);
    SKSpriteNode *hathpace = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"hathpace"];
    hathpace.position = CGPointMake(x2, _groundHalfHeight + RUNNER_HEIGHT * 1.5);
    hathpace.name = ROCK_NAME;
    [_bgLayer addChild:hathpace];
}

- (void)checkCollisions {
    // Check the coins
    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:COIN_NAME
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
                                   SKSpriteNode *coin = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
                                   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(coin.frame, _runner.frame)) {
                                       [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"pickup_coin.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
                                       _coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Coins: %d", ++_coins];
                                       [coin removeFromParent];
                                   }
                               }];

    // Check the rocks
    [_bgLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:ROCK_NAME
                               usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
                                   SKSpriteNode *rock = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
                                   CGRect smallerFrame = CGRectInset(rock.frame, 20, 20);
                                   if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_runner.frame, smallerFrame)) {
                                       if (_runnerState == incredible) {
                                           [rock removeFromParent];
                                       }
                                       else {
                                           [self gameOver];
                                       }
                                   }
                               }];
}

- (void)gameOver {
    NSLog(@"GameOver");
    _isGameOver = YES;
    [_runner removeActionForKey:RUNNER_ANIMATION_KEY];
    EndScene *endScene = [[EndScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size showStartButton:YES];
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:2.0];
    [self.view presentScene:endScene transition:reveal];

    _meter1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];

    if (_meter > _meter1) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_meter forKey:@"HighScoreSaved"];
    }
}

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if (_isGameOver) {
        return;
    }

    if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _dt = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

    // Runner faster than normal
    if (_runnerState == incredible) {
        _meter += INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC / BG_POINTS_PER_SEC;
        _meter1 += INCREDIBLE_BG_POINTS_PER_SEC / BG_POINTS_PER_SEC;
    }
    else {
        ++_meter;
        ++_meter1;
    }
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Meters", _meter];
    _highScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li High Score",(long) _meter1];

    [self checkCollisions];
    [self moveBackground];
}
@end
```

Comment: Learning how to use the debugger would have solved this issue long ago. Setting a breakpoint takes all of a half second to do, and then you can step through to explore why what you expect to happen, isn't. As the current answer notes `_isGameOver` is a likely candidate as it returns you from the update method immediately if that flag is set.

Comment: @prototypical, thanks for the response. Will check it out tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution and believe me i am about to smack myself on the head for not seeing that. the whole code was working except the part `(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime` where i was adding `++_meter1;` which is completely unnecessary since there is no need of adding any high score at this point. in that part i just needed to update the score. the addition of the score plus high score is taking place in `(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size` anyway and i was mis coding that. i just commented out the `++_meter1;` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is add `NSLog` messages to `- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime` method and see what happened after player die, also check `_isGameOver` variable is looks suspicious for me:)

Comment: Thank pal. I will try to do something with it tonight when I get home. I think in collision when I check for game did end I need to make some adjustments. I will update the code above tonight.

Comment: did that. everything seems alright. i can't understand where I'm going wrong. i uploaded the code for the entire class in edit section of my question. can you take a look?

Comment: can you set breakpoint in `- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime ` to second line (`return;`) to determine that is called/not called when your label is not updates

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never set isGameOver to NO. Your update method is likely returning every time it runs.

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment

Comment: @bjhaid, I agree but if he can improve it by posting some codes I'll still consider it.

Comment: @Lurker, thanks man, i figured it out. +1 for trying to help.:)